# horizontal layout scrolled

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I'm going to design a page like this. The main problem about my designed page is that it is too short. I want each of my button to be wider. like what you can see in the picture.
If I add fix number to my linear layout it works but it is not responsive any more.
[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:background="#FF2200"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="Button" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="Button" />
                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:background="#FF2200"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="Button" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="Button" />
                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:background="#FF2200"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="Button" />




            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:background="#FF2200"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="Button" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:background="#FF2200"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="Button" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="Button" />



            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>





    </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the HorizontalLayout, the child's width must wrap content :

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalLayout>
```

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't changed any thing

Comment: You should also use `layout_width="wrap_content"` for all other children and set a specific width for your buttons

Comment: what do you mean by saying that " a specific width for your buttons "? If when I give each button a fixed size it is not responsive any more

Comment: Something like "100dp". Because I understood you want those buttons to be wider, like in the image you posted.

Comment: You should clarify what you want, because in the picture, images have all the same size, which is fixed.

Comment: It did not solve my problem, since it different pages with different size the buttons trun to rectangular. Is there any way to fix the size of buttons based of screen size by programming?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want... Why are you using an HorizontalScrollView? It seems you want your buttons to have same width than others and that they fill the screen. Is it?

Comment: Tanks for your patience

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I want to make a list of images in two rows and I want each of rows to have 10 images or buttons. I want My images to be large enough to be seen by users easily. Consequently, as the some android devices have a small screen if I add twenty images at one time it won't be easy for users to see. But if I add a horizontal scroll I can have large images in all screens.